# Built installation usb key from linux virtual machine

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine I'd like to install as real os on my machine.

As I have refit installed on my macbook air (Mac os, windows and ubuntu), I tried the clonezilla methode in order to overwrite my existing linux partition but that caused me a boot problem on linux and windows (I think a partition table problem)

So I wanted to know if there is any way to make a bootable installation usb key from this installation on vm (that configuration have to be deployed on several machine that why I'd like to perform this solution)

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 0):

you can download installation iso file and use Startup Disk Creator to flash it to your USB key.